# the sum of two unbounded normal operators

Tags: discrete-mathematics, operator-theory

[image]

why A and B are normal?and why "0" is not closed on H1(R)?

Comment: Is the tag discrete-mathematics on purpose? Maybe it should be removed?

Answer (score 0):

Check that $A^* = -A$, so $A A^* = - A^2 = A^* A$.  It is **not** obvious that the domain of $A^*$ is the same as the domain of $A$, but I'm guessing this was already done in previous examples.

$0$ restricted to $H^1$ is not closed because if $f_j$ is a sequence in $H^1$ whose $L^2$ limit $f$ is not in $H^1$, $(f, 0)$ is in the closure of the graph but not in the graph itself.